# Inline editing mode an dynamic object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dynamic, grid, kendo-ui, inline-editing

I've created a grid with a dynamic object and I'd like to use the GridEditMode.InLine to update and add data. The popUp mode is working but with the InCell and 
the inline I'm getting the following error:

**Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.**

Am I missing something?

I tried to use a custom template but I am still getting the same error.

Thanks for your help

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<dynamic>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .ServerOperation(true)
        .Model(cfg =>
         {
           cfg.Id("SsdID");
        foreach (var property in Model.PropertyDescriptors)
            {
                cfg.Field(property.Name, property.DataType);
             }
         })
        .Read(cfg => cfg.Type(HttpVerbs.Post)
        .Action("ReadDataForDefinition", "ManualDataEntry",
                new { id = Model.LDefinitionId }))
        .Update(u => u.Type(HttpVerbs.Post).Action("UpdateDataForDefinition","ManualDataEntry",
                new { id = Model.LDefinitionId }))
        .Create(u => u.Type(HttpVerbs.Post).Action("Create", "ManualDataEntry",
                new { id = Model.LDefinitionId }))
         )
      .Resizable(resizing => resizing.Columns(true))
      Columns(columns =>
      {
        foreach (var property in Model.PropertyDescriptors.Where(desc => desc.DisplayOrder.HasValue))
         {
             var binding = columns.Bound(property.DataType, property.Name);
          if (property.DataType == typeof(DateTime) || property.DataType ==typeof(DateTime?))
           binding.Format("{0:d}");
           binding.Column.Title = property.Label;
          }
      columns.Command(command =>
        {
            command.Edit();
            command.Destroy();
        });
     })
  .ToolBar(toolbar => { toolbar.Create(); })
  .Pageable(paging =>
   {
        paging.ButtonCount(10);
        paging.PreviousNext(true);
        paging.PageSizes(true);
    })
  .Editable(edit => edit.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
  .Sortable()
  .Scrollable()
  .Filterable()
)
```

Answer (score 1):

For such scenarios only PopUp edit mode is supported. InLine and InCell editing modes are not supported when the using dynamic data or DataTable because the Grid cannot resolve the types of the columns and therefore cannot create proper editor templates. You could check the type and assign templates manually as a workaround. For example:

```
.Columns(columns =>
{
  foreach (System.Data.DataColumn column in Model.Columns)
  {
    switch (column.DataType.ToString())
    {
        case "System.Int16":
        case "System.Int32":
        case "System.Int64":
            columns.Bound(column.ColumnName).EditorTemplateName("Integer");
            break;
        case "System.Decimal":
        case "System.Double":
        case "System.Float":
            columns.Bound(column.ColumnName).EditorTemplateName("Number");
            break;
        case "System.String":
            columns.Bound(column.ColumnName).EditorTemplateName("String");
            break;
        default:
            //etc etc
            break;
    }
  }
})
```