# Kendo UI MVC grid not seeing Model.Columns data

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, mvc-editor-templates

Hey all I am using **Kendo UI** for **ASP.NET MVC** version 2022.R1.SP1 and I have populated a grid with one row:

[image]

The above screenshot grid works only when I comment out the **FOREEACH** statement in the code below  I am using to populate that grid above is this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Dtos.ConfigurationItemDto>()
    .Name("grbConfigSettings")
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
    .ColumnMenu()
    .Filterable()
    .ToolBar(t => t.Search())
    .Search(s => {
        s.Field(o => o.Value, "contains");
    })
    .Height("90%")
    .Selectable(s => s.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
    .Resizable(r => r.Columns(true))
    .Sortable()
    .Pageable(p =>
    {
        p.Refresh(true);
        p.PageSizes((IEnumerable<int>)new List<int> { 50, 100, 250, 500 });
        p.PreviousNext(true);
        p.Input(true);
        p.AlwaysVisible(true);
    }
    )
    .Editable(g=>g.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
    .Columns(c =>
    {
        foreach (System.Data.DataColumn column in Model.Columns)
        {
            switch (column.DataType.ToString())
            {
                case "System.Int16":
                case "System.Int32":
                case "System.Int64":
                    c.Bound(column.ColumnName).EditorTemplateName("Integer");
                    break;
                case "System.Decimal":
                case "System.Double":
                case "System.Float":
                    c.Bound(column.ColumnName).EditorTemplateName("Number");
                    break;
                case "System.String":
                    c.Bound(column.ColumnName).EditorTemplateName("String");
                    break;
                default:
                    //etc etc
                    break;
            }
        }
        c.Bound(m => m.Id).Hidden();
        c.Bound(m => m.NameSpace);
        c.Bound(m => m.Key);
        c.Bound(m => m.Type);
        c.Bound(m => m.Value);
        c.Command(cmd =>
        {
            cmd.Edit();
        });
    })
    .Scrollable()
    .DataSource(
        ds => ds
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(50)
        .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Configuration"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("Update", "Configuration"))
        .Model(m =>
        {
            m.Id(c => c.Id);
            m.Field(c => c.Key).Editable(false);
            m.Field(c => c.Type).Editable(false);
            m.Field(c => c.NameSpace).Editable(false);
            m.Field(c => c.Value).Editable(true);
        }
        )
    )
)
```

Every time I try loading the page I get the error of:

> Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

Which does not make any sense since I know there are at least 1 row of data in the grid.

I originally used the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21176081/inline-editing-mode-an-dynamic-object) but seeing as it was posted in 2017 - its a little outdated. I have also seen this [demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/OxOSIzil) from Telerik's demo site but that seems to just be using **jQuery** and not **ASP.NET MVC**?

My goal would be to see what type that current row is (in the image above that would be a **4** which would indicate a **numeric only value**) and change the **EditorTemplateName** to reflect this. There will be **different types of modes** for this column so that is why I am needing to **dynamically** change that **rows edit type for each row**.

So, what am I missing or doing wrong here?

Comment: What do you mean by "There will be different types of modes for this column"?

Comment: @ShawnOrr Meaning one record could have only numbers for that column then the next record could only have values that need to be in a dropdown list, etc etc. That column wont have just a single type.